# Is Keyrock's Project the same as Fiware-Service?

Tags: fiware

I'm studying Keyrock's functionalities and I have the following questions:

- Are Projects the same that Fiware-Service?
- Are Applications the same that Fiware-ServicePath?

Thanks,

Gabriel

Answer (score 2):

I think that the IdM Keyrock has not a mapping between the Fiware-Service/Fiware-ServicePath headers and entities in IdM keystone data model. In Fact looking into the PEP Proxy code I could not find a reference to this headers (I did a "search everywhere" in the project source code =D ).

This is, from my point of view quite interesting. Sadly I have not much experience with this implementation of the IdM GE, in fact I workerd with the Telefonica implementations of the IdM, PEP Proxy and Authorization PDP GEs.

What I can tell you for sure, is that Telefonica implementations and GING implementations are quite different. For example the Telefonica's Keystone has a direct mapping between Fiware-Service and Fiware-ServicePath wich is by the way the following:

- Fiware-Service: Keystone Domain
- Fiware-ServicePath: Keystone Project

In the case of the GING's Keystone, I believe that they use a single Keystone domain called "Default" and inside this domain they have organizations represented as Keystone projects. How ever, the thing seems much more complicated because GING bases his authentication model in OAuth2. Looking into de IdM data model (I enabled MySQL persistence and then saw the database schema) I did not see any relationship beetween OAuth2 applications (take a look to the table called "consumer_oauth2") and Fiware-Service or Fiware-ServicePath headers.

I think that some kind of orientation from the Fiware people, would be very helpful at this point because I have the same question.

I hope my answer has been helpful at some point.

Comment: What you say makes sense, but I'm not totally sure that's right.
I think that would be very important if something at GING confirms that.